# AVL trees - insert elements with indexes and store two trees | Data structure

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, computer-science, avl-tree

I need help to understand the solution for the following data structure question:

**Question:**

Suggest an ADT containing integers that supports the following actions. Explain how these
actions are implemented.

Init() - Initialize the ADT O(1)
Insert(x) - Insert x into the ADT, if it is not in ADT yet O(log n)
Delete(x) - Delete x from the ADT, if exists O(log n)
Delete_in_place(i) - Delete from the ADT an element, which is in the ith
place (as determined by the order of insertion) among
the elements that are in the ADT at that moment.
O(log n)
Get_place(x) - Return the place (which is determined by the order of
insertion) of x among the elements that are in the ADT
at that moment. If x does not exist, return -1.
O(log n)

For example, for the following sequence of actions:
Insert(3), Insert(5), Insert(11), Insert(4), Insert(7), Delete(5)
Get_place(7) returns 4, and Delete_in_place(2) will delete 11 from the tree

**Solution:**

The ADT consists of 2 AVL trees.
- T1 stores the elements by their key.
- T2 stores the elements by the order of insertion (using a running counter). To this tree
new element will be inserted as the greatest from all elements in this tree. The nodes
of this tree store also the number of elements in their subtree – x.size. Each node has a
pointer to his father.
- There are pointers between all the trees connecting the nodes with the same key.

[Here is an example of the two trees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uJ9O.jpg)

***Init()*** – initialize 2 empty trees
***Insert(x)*** – insert an element by key into T1, insert the element as the biggest to T2, and
update the pointers. Update the in T2 the field x.size in the insertion path. (The insertion is as
in AVL tree)
***Delete(x)*** – find the element in T1 (regular search), and delete it from both the trees. In T2 go
up from the deleted element to the root and update x.size for all the nodes in this path. (The
deletion is as in AVL tree)

***Delete_by_place(i) –***

```
Delete_by_place(i) – find the ith element in T2 in the following way:
 x←T2.root
 if x.size<i return
 while(x!=null)
   if x.left = null
     z←0
   else
     z←x.left.size
   if (i ≤ z)
     x←x.left
   else if (i = z + 1)
     Delete(x) and break
   else // i > z+1
     i ← i – (z + 1)
   x←x.right
```

***Get_place(x) –*** find x in T1, go by its pointer to T2, then calculate the index of x in the tree –
Go up from x to the root. In this path sum the number of nodes that are in the left subtree of
the nodes in the path that are smaller than x:

```
 place←1
 place←place+x.left.size
 while (x.parent != null)
 {
   if (x is left_child of x.parent)
     x←x.parent
   else //x is right child
     place←place+1+x.parent.left.size
     x←x.parent
 }
 return place
```

**My Questions -**
How do I insert to T2 tree? in the attached photo there is an example of this tree and I don't understand how it was build?

Since it is written that this is an AVL tree, do we perform the rotations? how do we keep it balanced? it doesn't act as a BST...

How does Delete_in_place(i) works? i've tried to run it with the example in the photo and didn't received the correct index.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is it necessary to use two AVL trees, or an array for indexing can be used?

Comment: You can use what you like as long as the time complexity is O(logn)